# Close handle to a mutex in another process

Tags: c++, mutex

I want to close a handle to a mutex located in another process, so I can run more than one instance of the application.

I already know this can be done, [see Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). Example: Windows *Minesweeper* (Windows 7) uses a mutex to only allow one game, so I thought I would use it as an example since it's pre-installed with Windows and therefore easier for you guys to guide me.

The mutex that I need to close is `\Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\Oberon_Minesweeper_Singleton`, which I found using Process Explorer.

After closing this mutex I was able to launch two games of *Minesweeper*, but I want to do this in my program using C++.

After some searching I have found that I might need the API [DuplicateHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So far I haven't been able to close the handle on this mutex.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printerror(LPSTR location){
    printf("Error: %s_%d", location, GetLastError());
    cin.get();
}

int main(){
    DWORD pid = 0;
    HWND hMineWnd = FindWindow("Minesweeper", "Minesveiper");
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hMineWnd, &pid);
    HANDLE hProc =OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, 0, pid);
    if(hProc == NULL){
        printerror("1");
        return 1;
    }
    HANDLE hMutex = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, "Oberon_Minesweeper_Singleton");
    if(hMutex == NULL){
        printerror("2");
        return 2;
    }
    if(DuplicateHandle(hProc, hMutex, NULL, 0, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE) == 0){
        printerror("3");
        return 3;
    }
    if(CloseHandle(hMutex) == 0){
        printerror("4");
        return 4;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code returns 0, but the mutex is still there, and I am not able to launch more games of Minesweeper. I think some of my parameters to DuplicateHandle are wrong.

Comment: That kind of mutex was high on the list of XP SP1 vulnerabilities that Microsoft got into after being attacked mercilessly.  Denial of Service, DOS got a different meaning.  You are enjoying the counter-measures.  What exactly was the point of doing this again?

Comment: @HansPassant The goal is to go pass the Mutex lock and be able to run more than one of the same application.

Comment: You are *definitely* missing the point of a "singleton application".  Just type that in a google query.

Comment: Why "Minesveiper" for the second parameter to `FindWindow`? Is it on a Norwegian version of Windows? *[Minesveiper](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minesveiper)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `DuplicateHandle` expects *"an open object handle that is valid in the context of the source process"*, however I believe the handle you're passing in would only be valid within the current process (`OpenMutex` creates a new handle to an existing mutex object). You'll likely need to determine what the mutex's handle is in the remote process, and use that value when calling `DuplicateHandle`.

Comment: Thx for your fast reply, have you any suggestion on how to get the handle from the remote process?

Comment: Typically the local and remote processes would share the handle ID via  inter-process communication (sockets, pipes, shared memory, etc). Since you don't control the remote process, I'm not sure how you would retrieve this information.

Comment: I thought maybe injecting a .dll to pass the handle from remote process, but wouldn't it be easier to remove the mutex from the injected .dll?

Comment: You may want to update the question to describe what you're final solution was (or add an additional answer) for future reference.

Comment: It was your answer, the second parameter was incorrect, by hard-coding it (using handle id) i was able to close the mutex.

Comment: I have the same need. I was able to execute the DuplicateHandle() successfully. However, when I tried to call ReleaseMutex(), it gave me the error ERROR_NOT_OWNER. WePro2, did you see this error from your code?