# Close Handle after Duplicate

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I was trying to close a handle to a Mutex of an extern process.
Therefore I tried to use [DuplicateHandle from the Win32API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251(v=vs.85).aspx) as [seen in this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690969/close-handle-to-a-mutex-in-another-process)

Closing the handle on the target process works. Closing it after duplicating it to my current process however does not. Strangely it also seems to duplicate the handle twice!

```
public class Win32API
    {
        [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
        public static extern int NtQueryObject(IntPtr ObjectHandle, int
            ObjectInformationClass, IntPtr ObjectInformation, int ObjectInformationLength,
            ref int returnLength);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint QueryDosDevice(string lpDeviceName, StringBuilder lpTargetPath, int ucchMax);

        [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
        public static extern uint NtQuerySystemInformation(int
            SystemInformationClass, IntPtr SystemInformation, int SystemInformationLength,
            ref int returnLength);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenMutex(UInt32 desiredAccess, bool inheritHandle, string name);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool DuplicateHandle(IntPtr hSourceProcessHandle,
           ushort hSourceHandle, IntPtr hTargetProcessHandle, out IntPtr lpTargetHandle,
           uint dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, uint dwOptions);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

        public enum ObjectInformationClass : int
        {
            ObjectBasicInformation = 0,
            ObjectNameInformation = 1,
            ObjectTypeInformation = 2,
            ObjectAllTypesInformation = 3,
            ObjectHandleInformation = 4
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
        {
            All = 0x001F0FFF,
            Terminate = 0x00000001,
            CreateThread = 0x00000002,
            VMOperation = 0x00000008,
            VMRead = 0x00000010,
            VMWrite = 0x00000020,
            DupHandle = 0x00000040,
            SetInformation = 0x00000200,
            QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
            Synchronize = 0x00100000
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION
        { // Information Class 0
            public int Attributes;
            public int GrantedAccess;
            public int HandleCount;
            public int PointerCount;
            public int PagedPoolUsage;
            public int NonPagedPoolUsage;
            public int Reserved1;
            public int Reserved2;
            public int Reserved3;
            public int NameInformationLength;
            public int TypeInformationLength;
            public int SecurityDescriptorLength;
            public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME CreateTime;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION
        { // Information Class 2
            public UNICODE_STRING Name;
            public int ObjectCount;
            public int HandleCount;
            public int Reserved1;
            public int Reserved2;
            public int Reserved3;
            public int Reserved4;
            public int PeakObjectCount;
            public int PeakHandleCount;
            public int Reserved5;
            public int Reserved6;
            public int Reserved7;
            public int Reserved8;
            public int InvalidAttributes;
            public GENERIC_MAPPING GenericMapping;
            public int ValidAccess;
            public byte Unknown;
            public byte MaintainHandleDatabase;
            public int PoolType;
            public int PagedPoolUsage;
            public int NonPagedPoolUsage;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION
        { // Information Class 1
            public UNICODE_STRING Name;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct UNICODE_STRING
        {
            public ushort Length;
            public ushort MaximumLength;
            public IntPtr Buffer;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct GENERIC_MAPPING
        {
            public int GenericRead;
            public int GenericWrite;
            public int GenericExecute;
            public int GenericAll;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
        { // Information Class 16
            public int ProcessID;
            public byte ObjectTypeNumber;
            public byte Flags; // 0x01 = PROTECT_FROM_CLOSE, 0x02 = INHERIT
            public ushort Handle;
            public int Object_Pointer;
            public UInt32 GrantedAccess;
        }

        public const int MAX_PATH = 260;
        public const uint STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = 0xC0000004;
        public const int DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS = 0x2;
        public const int DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE = 0x1;
    }

    public class Win32Processes
    {
        const int CNST_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION = 16;
        const uint STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = 0xc0000004;

        public static string getObjectTypeName(Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION shHandle, Process process)
        {
            IntPtr m_ipProcessHwnd = Win32API.OpenProcess(Win32API.ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, process.Id);
            IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            var objBasic = new Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION();
            IntPtr ipBasic = IntPtr.Zero;
            var objObjectType = new Win32API.OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION();
            IntPtr ipObjectType = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr ipObjectName = IntPtr.Zero;
            string strObjectTypeName = "";
            int nLength = 0;
            int nReturn = 0;
            IntPtr ipTemp = IntPtr.Zero;
        

            if (!Win32API.DuplicateHandle(m_ipProcessHwnd, shHandle.Handle,
                                          Win32API.GetCurrentProcess(), out ipHandle,
                                          0, false, Win32API.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
                return null;
                
            ipBasic = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic));
            Win32API.NtQueryObject(ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectBasicInformation,
                                   ipBasic, Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic), ref nLength);
            objBasic = (Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipBasic, objBasic.GetType());
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipBasic);

            ipObjectType = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(objBasic.TypeInformationLength);
            nLength = objBasic.TypeInformationLength;
            while ((uint)(nReturn = Win32API.NtQueryObject(
                ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectTypeInformation, ipObjectType,
                  nLength, ref nLength)) ==
                Win32API.STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectType);
                ipObjectType = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
            }

            objObjectType = (Win32API.OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipObjectType, objObjectType.GetType());
            if (Is64Bits())
            {
                ipTemp = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt64(objObjectType.Name.Buffer.ToString(), 10) >> 32);
            }
            else
            {
                ipTemp = objObjectType.Name.Buffer;
            }

            strObjectTypeName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ipTemp, objObjectType.Name.Length >> 1);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectType);
            return strObjectTypeName;
        }


        public static string getObjectName(Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION shHandle, Process process)
        {
            IntPtr m_ipProcessHwnd = Win32API.OpenProcess(Win32API.ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, process.Id);
            IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            var objBasic = new Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION();
            IntPtr ipBasic = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr ipObjectType = IntPtr.Zero;
            var objObjectName = new Win32API.OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION();
            IntPtr ipObjectName = IntPtr.Zero;
            string strObjectName = "";
            int nLength = 0;
            int nReturn = 0;
            IntPtr ipTemp = IntPtr.Zero;
        
            if (!Win32API.DuplicateHandle(m_ipProcessHwnd, shHandle.Handle, Win32API.GetCurrentProcess(),
                                          out ipHandle, 0, false, Win32API.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
                return null;
                
            ipBasic = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic));
            Win32API.NtQueryObject(ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectBasicInformation,
                                   ipBasic, Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic), ref nLength);
            objBasic = (Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipBasic, objBasic.GetType());
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipBasic);


            nLength = objBasic.NameInformationLength;

            ipObjectName = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
            while ((uint)(nReturn = Win32API.NtQueryObject(
                     ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectNameInformation,
                     ipObjectName, nLength, ref nLength))
                   == Win32API.STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectName);
                ipObjectName = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
            }
            objObjectName = (Win32API.OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipObjectName, objObjectName.GetType());

            if (Is64Bits())
            {
                ipTemp = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt64(objObjectName.Name.Buffer.ToString(), 10) >> 32);
            }
            else
            {
                ipTemp = objObjectName.Name.Buffer;
            }

            if (ipTemp != IntPtr.Zero)
            {

                byte[] baTemp2 = new byte[nLength];
                try
                {
                    Marshal.Copy(ipTemp, baTemp2, 0, nLength);

                    strObjectName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Is64Bits() ?
                                                           new IntPtr(ipTemp.ToInt64()) :
                                                           new IntPtr(ipTemp.ToInt32()));
                    return strObjectName;
                }
                catch (AccessViolationException)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectName);
                    Win32API.CloseHandle(ipHandle);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static List<Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION>
        GetHandles(Process process = null, string IN_strObjectTypeName = null, string IN_strObjectName = null)
        {
            uint nStatus;
            int nHandleInfoSize = 0x10000;
            IntPtr ipHandlePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nHandleInfoSize);
            int nLength = 0;
            IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

            while ((nStatus = Win32API.NtQuerySystemInformation(CNST_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, ipHandlePointer,
                                                                nHandleInfoSize, ref nLength)) ==
                    STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
            {
                nHandleInfoSize = nLength;
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipHandlePointer);
                ipHandlePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
            }

            byte[] baTemp = new byte[nLength];
            Marshal.Copy(ipHandlePointer, baTemp, 0, nLength);

            long lHandleCount = 0;
            if (Is64Bits())
            {
                lHandleCount = Marshal.ReadInt64(ipHandlePointer);
                ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandlePointer.ToInt64() + 8);
            }
            else
            {
                lHandleCount = Marshal.ReadInt32(ipHandlePointer);
                ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandlePointer.ToInt32() + 4);
            }

            Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION shHandle;
            List<Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION> lstHandles = new List<Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION>();

            for (long lIndex = 0; lIndex < lHandleCount; lIndex++)
            {
                shHandle = new Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION();
                if (Is64Bits())
                {
                    shHandle = (Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipHandle, shHandle.GetType());
                    ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandle.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(shHandle) + 8);
                }
                else
                {
                    ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandle.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(shHandle));
                    shHandle = (Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipHandle, shHandle.GetType());
                }

                if (process != null)
                {
                    if (shHandle.ProcessID != process.Id) continue;
                }

                string strObjectTypeName = "";
                if (IN_strObjectTypeName != null)
                {
                    strObjectTypeName = getObjectTypeName(shHandle, Process.GetProcessById(shHandle.ProcessID));
                    if (strObjectTypeName != IN_strObjectTypeName) continue;
                }

                string strObjectName = "";
                if (IN_strObjectName != null)
                {
                    strObjectName = getObjectName(shHandle, Process.GetProcessById(shHandle.ProcessID));
                    if (strObjectName != IN_strObjectName) continue;
                }

                string strObjectTypeName2 = getObjectTypeName(shHandle, Process.GetProcessById(shHandle.ProcessID));
                string strObjectName2 = getObjectName(shHandle, Process.GetProcessById(shHandle.ProcessID));
                MessageBox.Show(shHandle.ProcessID.ToString() + "\n" +strObjectTypeName2.ToString() + "\n" + strObjectName2.ToString());

                lstHandles.Add(shHandle);
            }
            return lstHandles;
        }

        public static bool Is64Bits()
        {
            return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) == 8 ? true : false;
        }
    }

class MutexCloser
{
    public void CloseMutex(string ProcessName, string MutexName)
    {

        try
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName)[0];
            var handles = Win32Processes.GetHandles(process, "Mutant", "\\Sessions\\1\\BaseNamedObjects\\" + MutexName);
            if (handles.Count == 0) throw new System.ArgumentException("NoMutex", "original");
            foreach (var handle in handles)
            {
                IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                Win32API.DuplicateHandle(Process.GetProcessById(handle.ProcessID).Handle, handle.Handle, Win32API.GetCurrentProcess(), out ipHandle, 0, false, Win32API.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE);
                Win32API.CloseHandle(ipHandle);
                MessageBox.Show("Mutex was killed");
            }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The process name '{0}' is not currently running", ProcessName);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Mutex " + MutexName + "  was not found in the process " + ProcessName);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I using the wrong Handle IP here?

```
IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                Win32API.DuplicateHandle(Process.GetProcessById(handle.ProcessID).Handle, handle.Handle, Win32API.GetCurrentProcess(), out ipHandle, 0, false, Win32API.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE);
                Win32API.CloseHandle(ipHandle);
```

My target process is a 64-bit applicaton.

EDIT: Just to clarify. I want to close the duplicated handle or if somebody has an idea for a simplified version of closing a handle on another process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a handle leak: `getObjectTypeName()` function duplicates the handle it is passed but never closes the duplicate.

That extra handle will be keeping the mutex alive, even though the target process no longer has a handle to it.

Comment: Thousand thanks! Was searching for this for hours now!